# Regular Expressions in APEX for a field

Tags: validation, regular-expressions

I'm new to APEX and was writing a validation function for a field called DESIGNATION.  I have the REGEX that that looks like this:

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9=.\-\/\s+]{1,49})
```

The designation field must begin with an a-z, A-Z or 0-9 and be followed by 1 to 49 more characters that are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 an equal sign, a period, a hyphen, a backslash, or a space character.  This field must be one character long and can be a total of 50 characters long.

Here is a screen shot of the validation screen:

[image: Page Validation]

When I go to run my app on the screen called SYNOPTIC with the designation field on it to validate and type "AZC A }{}**##" which has the bad characters of '}{}**##' in it, it allow the row to be updated and shouldn't

[image: UI]

So my question is, is it the regular expression that is the issue or the Type field being "Item/Column in Expression 1 matches Regular Expression in Expression 2", or a combination of both?  If my regular expression is bad then how do I fix it?

Comment: Just a note, field names cannot start with a number.

Answer (score 3):

The dot has a special meaning in regular expressions and so any character is valid. You need to escape the dot with a backslash for it to work. Moreover you stated that a backslash should be matched, but your expression would match a forward slash instead. To change this you need to replace `\/` with `\\`. Altogether this leads to something like this:

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9=\.\-\\\s+]{1,49})
```

A good resource to test regular expressions that also gives a detailed explanation of the current meaning of the expression is [regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, Markus.  Well, I even reduced my expression down to ([A-Z,0-9]{1,50}) and it still allows bad characters such as #${} into my designation field.  I think that it is an issue with getting the right Type and the right Condition Type field to sync up with my regex.  I have a Type of "Item/Column in Expression 1 matches Regular Expression in Expression 2", and a Condition Type of "Always" set for whenever the SUBMIT (Save Changes) button is pressed.  So my question now becomes, do I have the right settings for my regex?