# Salesforce - Data Validation - last character must be a letter

Tags: formula, validation

I need a data validation formula to say, if status is "Registered" and ID is 6 characters long, the last character of the ID must be a letter.

I have managed to get this far but come to a brick wall;

```
AND( 
    ISPICKVAL( Referral_Status__c , 'Registered'), 
    LEN( Name ) = 6,
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use a Regular Expression in validation.  See this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/172157/regular-expressions-in-apex-for-a-field).

The RegEx could enforce both length requirement as well as the letter requirement on character 6 (along with other things, like if you wanted to check for only alphanumerics in the first 5).

For example:

`boolean passes = Pattern.matches('^[\w]{5}[a-zA-Z]$');`

or perhaps if you want a more explicit regex:

`boolean passes = Pattern.matches('^[a-zA-Z_0-9]{5}[a-zA-Z]$');`

Answer (score 0):

The [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=5) documentation is a good resource here (albeit one that has a pretty abysmal UX).

There are several functions to get a substring, but probably the easiest one to use here given your description would be `RIGHT(1)` combined with `REGEX()` to test for an alphabetic character